# Better design REST endpoints with .antMatchers()

Tags: java, spring, rest, security

I am designing REST API for Spring Boot application and I have an issue with its design. I would like to start all my REST endpoints with prefix `/project_name/v1/`.

I have hundreds of endpoints which witch are protected with authentification and only a pair which need to be accessible without authentification.

This is **current state**:

```
Method | Endpoint                       | Secure
------------------------------------------------------------------
POST   | /project_name/activate         | accessible to everybody
GET    | /project_name/activate/{id}    | accessible to everybody
GET    | /project_name/v1/getAllUsers/  | protected by token
GET    | /project_name/v1/getUser/{id}  | protected by token
POST   | /project_name/v1/createUser/   | protected by token
...    | /project_name/v1/...           | protected by token
```

This is **desired state**:

```
Method | Endpoint                       | Secure
------------------------------------------------------------------
POST   | /project_name/v1/activate      | accessible to everybody
GET    | /project_name/v1/activate/{id} | accessible to everybody
GET    | /project_name/v1/getAllUsers/  | protected by token
GET    | /project_name/v1/getUser/{id}  | protected by token
POST   | /project_name/v1/createUser/   | protected by token
...    | /project_name/v1/...           | protected by token
```

I have tired several approaches. E.g.:

- I tried to play with the order of .antMatchers() while as far as I understand order matter. This approach does not work while because if anything is declared on the same path first as .authenticated() than anything else cannot be .permitAll(); if reversed - .permitAll() makes everything not required to be .authenticated()
- I have listed all specific endpoints in .antMatchers() with appropriate authorization. Again order probably matter and got into the same issue as previous.

Simply nothing that I tried worked.

Is there a way to have unauthenticated and protected endpoints under one common path with using .permitAll() and .authenticated()?

Current solution works.  This is ResourceServerConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@SuppressWarnings("DesignForExtension")
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfiguration(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public final void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/project_name/activate/v1/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/project_name/v1/**").authenticated();
            http.servletApi().rolePrefix("");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenStore(this.tokenStore);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The matchers are considered in the order they appear, if you want to secure everything BUT 2 endpoints probably you'll need something like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@SuppressWarnings("DesignForExtension")
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfiguration(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public final void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/project_name/v1/**").authenticated();
                .antMatchers("/project_name/v1/activate/**").permitAll()
            http.servletApi().rolePrefix("");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenStore(this.tokenStore);
    }
}
```

This way Spring Security will override only the v1/activate/** path with anonymous access and leaving the other included in v1/** secured.

Comment: This approach does not work. I get an error regarding required authorization. But I come up with the right solution. The twist is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rafura suggestion I tried to come up with the solution. The twist is in the order of the endpoints. Following solution works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@SuppressWarnings("DesignForExtension")
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfiguration(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public final void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/project_name/v1/activate/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/project_name/v1/**").authenticated();
            http.servletApi().rolePrefix("");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenStore(this.tokenStore);
    }
}
```

I guess the Spring first map specific endpoint with the appropriate path. And then fill up the rest of the endpoints which it will find with the rest of the authorization level.

**Note to rafura answer:**
Reversed order does not work. Probably because everything below certain path gets authorization and when Spring finds the specific endpoint which is listed, it is already noted as required authorization. As described in this answer above, reverse order works.